# Unable to run embedded mongo flapdoodle in GitHub Actions Maven build

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, maven, github-actions, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

I have a SpringBoot project pushed to GitHub and inside it I have some semi-integration tests in which I use embedded mongo as a database. My build is successfull locally and tests are passing but when running the "Java with Maven" GitHub action, it fails with the following:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoServer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable]: Factory method 'embeddedMongoServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not move /tmp/embedmongo-download-8a0542da-3c32-4e65-9aa8-b6da3e8d9ca4.TGZ to /home/runner/.embedmongo/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.5.5.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue using Jenkins+Docker(maven 3.8-openjdk-11). I also pulled the image and run the build in local docker, everything goes well.
Then I realized that I have a **parallel pipeline** stage in the jenkins file. I think that's the cause of the error. The multiple maven test stages(for multiple sub-modules) trying to move the file at the same time.
For me I just **change the test stage from parallel to non-parallel** solved my issue.